# 8Khz vs 48Khz audio sampling and noise expectations

Tags: audio

I'm messing around with this dac/dsp combo going into my picmx32.   Finally I have loopback stable and working cleanly at 48Khz sample rate.   This is a little too much data for me though so I want to bring the sample rate down to 8Khz.   When I do that audio still works but there are two things that bother me.

First the noise increases, or it seems to turn into a more of a hissing noise like background noise on an un-tuned radio or TV.   Maybe the noise is there but cleaner at 48Khz, I can't tell.

Second I get what sounds like a metallic tone that starts to show up when I record sound with the mic.

My question is, mainly about the noise, is this to be expected?   If this noise increase at lower sample rate is just a fundamental concept that I'm not familiar with then I'd like to learn about it.  If not I'll try to debug it more myself.   But no sense hunting it down if it's just a fact of lower sampling rates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like there are two things going on here.

At the lower sample rate, high frequency noise that was previously picked up as such and subsequently filtered out now aliases into frequencies you can hear.  If you want 8 kHz sample rate, sample at a higher rate, then low pass filter before dessimation.  You want the filters to attenuate frequencies beyond 4 kHz, since that's the maximum a 8 kHz sample stream can reproduce anyway.  Anything above 4 kHz when you sample at 8 kHz is going to become noise that you can't really get rid of later.

The metallic sound is usually a consequence of low resolution, like 8 bits.  The quantization noise at 8 bits does sound sortof "metallic".  Try sampling with more bits, like 12 or 16 per sample.

Comment: Ah I was afraid it might noise aliasing.   Thanks for the advice I'll try increasing the bits per sample too.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop - You sure about the 6 bits per sample? ;)

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Typo fixed.

Comment: He also may want to try an analog anti-aliasing LP filter in front of the ADC.